# Scraping Table using Beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

- How do i access the `<tr> tags inside <tbody>` using `find_all` in `for` loop because each `<tr>` seems independent from each other and has alternative class `'even'` and `'odd'`. I can only pass two args in `find_all`. i.e `find_all('tr', class_='odd')` or `(even)`
- Also how do I access only the 1st, 3rd, 4th and 6th  in each .
  The  tags do not have id or class.

## Code:

```
[from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
src_code = requests.get('https://bschool.careers360.com/colleges/ranking/2018').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src_code, features="html.parser")

i = 1
for trr in soup.find_all('tr', class_='odd'):
    i+=1
    college = trr.td.a.text
    print(college)
    if i%2==0:
        class_='even'
    else:
        class_='odd'][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all("tr",class_=['odd','even'])`

This gets all the tr tags then the td tag with a tag and the text of a tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
src_code = requests.get('https://bschool.careers360.com/colleges/ranking/2018').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src_code, features="html.parser")

alltr=soup.find_all("tr",class_=['odd','even'])

for x in alltr:
    print(x.td.a.text)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could find the parent tag first.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
src_code = requests.get('https://bschool.careers360.com/colleges/ranking/2018').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src_code, features="html5lib")
trs=soup.find(name = "div",id="related-results").find_all(name = "tr")
trs
```

the trs is what you want:

```
[<tr><th>College Name</th><th>Rank</th><th>Overall Score</th><th>Rating</th><th>Ownership</th><th>Intake Exams</th><th></th></tr>,
 <tr class="odd"><td><a href="https://www.careers360.com/university/indian-institute-of-management-ahmedabad">Indian Institute of Management Ahmedabad</a><br/></td><td><span class="serialNum circlerate Government"></span><span class="rankStyle">1</span></td><td><span class="overall_scoredata">427.92</span></td><td>AAAAA<div class="rankInfo"> <strong>2017 Rating: </strong> AAAAA</div></td><td><div class="ownership_name">Government</div><div class="rating_review rankInfo"><strong>User Rating: </strong>4.7 / 5</div></td><td><div class="showMoreCheck"> <input type="checkbox"/><div class="ranked_best_branch intakeExam"><div class="intakeExam ng-binding"><span class="best_branch plusMinus">CAT</span><ul><li>GMAT</li></ul></div></div></div></td><td><div class="rank-apply-button btnBlockInfo"><div class="flagging" id="divid-7057"><div class="flag-link flag-default-link"><a class="buttonDefault follow iframe-popup-button" href="/user/register?destination=colleges/ranking/2018&amp;nid=7057&amp;flag=bookmarks&amp;click_location=follow_button&amp;popup=iframe">Follow</a></div></div><div class="client_url"></div></div><div class="college-compare-checkbox combine-rating-block smallclListing"> <label> <input class="tmCheckbox" name="college_ranking" type="checkbox" value="7057"/><span></span> <i>Compare</i> </label></div></td></tr>,
 <tr class="even"><td><a href="https://www.careers360.com/university/indian-institute-of-management-bangalore">Indian Institute of Management Bangalore</a><br/></td><td><span class="serialNum circlerate Government"></span><span class="rankStyle">2</span></td><td><span class="overall_scoredata">408.32</span></td><td>AAAAA<div class="rankInfo"> <strong>2017 Rating: </strong> AAAAA</div></td><td><div class="ownership_name">Government</div><div class="rating_review rankInfo"><strong>User Rating: </strong>4.1 / 5</div></td><td><div class="showMoreCheck"> <input type="checkbox"/><div class="ranked_best_branch intakeExam"><div class="intakeExam ng-binding"><span class="best_branch plusMinus">CAT</span><ul><li>GMAT</li></ul></div></div></div></td><td><div class="rank-apply-button btnBlockInfo"><div class="flagging" id="divid-6872"><div class="flag-link flag-default-link"><a class="buttonDefault follow iframe-popup-button" href="/user/register?destination=colleges/ranking/2018&amp;nid=6872&amp;flag=bookmarks&amp;click_location=follow_button&amp;popup=iframe">Follow</a></div></div><div class="client_url"></div></div><div class="college-compare-checkbox combine-rating-block smallclListing"> <label> <input class="tmCheckbox" name="college_ranking" type="checkbox" value="6872"/><span></span> <i>Compare</i> </label></div></td></tr>,
 <tr class="odd"><td><a href="https://www.careers360.com/university/indian-institute-of-management-calcutta">Indian Institute of Management Calcutta</a><br/></td><td><span class="serialNum circlerate Government"></span><span class="rankStyle">3</span></td><td><span class="overall_scoredata">375.18</span></td><td>AAAAA<div class="rankInfo"> <strong>2017 Rating: </strong> AAAAA</div></td><td><div class="ownership_name">Government</div><div class="rating_review rankInfo"><strong>User Rating: </strong>4.9 / 5</div></td><td><div class="showMoreCheck"> <input type="checkbox"/><div class="ranked_best_branch intakeExam"><div class="intakeExam ng-binding"><span class="best_branch plusMinus">GMAT</span><ul><li>CAT</li></ul></div></div></div></td><td><div class="rank-apply-button btnBlockInfo"><div class="flagging" id="divid-6933"><div class="flag-link flag-default-link"><a class="buttonDefault follow iframe-popup-button" href="/user/register?destination=colleges/ranking/2018&amp;nid=6933&amp;flag=bookmarks&amp;click_location=follow_button&amp;popup=iframe">Follow</a></div></div><div class="client_url"></div></div><div class="college-compare-checkbox combine-rating-block smallclListing"> <label> <input class="tmCheckbox" name="college_ranking" type="checkbox" value="6933"/><span></span> <i>Compare</i> </label></div></td></tr>,
......
```